# Overriding vuetify sass variables which use another variable

Tags: vuetify.js

I've got my variables.scss file setup and working as per the docs. However if I try and override a variables which relies on another variable it throws an error.

I want to change

`$container-padding-x: $grid-gutter / 2 !default;`

To

`$container-padding-x: $grid-gutter !default;`

However I can't do this without also specifying $grid-gutter which in turn relies on $spacer so I end up having to define all 3. Is this expected behaviour?

Here's the build error I get...

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
6 │ $container-padding-x: $grid-gutter;
  │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/sass/variables.scss 6:23  @import
  src/sass/global.scss 1:9      root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the !default.

!default is used to prevent vuetify from overwriting your modifications, that means that when you change a sass variable, it will be set before vuetify, when vuetify variables are invoked, the !default will say if this variable is already set, ignore it.

`$container-padding-x: $grid-gutter`

Comment: It works fine for me both with or without the !default. The problem I have is I also have to specify both the $grid-gutter and $spacer variables or I get a build error. I've added the build error I get to the original question.

I also can't seem to over ride any of the $headers using either of the approaches shown in the documentation so I'm wondering if there is something wrong in my build setup somewhere? I don't get an error when overriding $headers is just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Which vuetify and vuetify-loader versions are you using?

Comment: "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
"vuetify": "^2.4.3"

I realised the problem with the $headers so ignore that. My question really is whether it's expected behaviour to have to specify $grid-gutter to use it as a value

Comment: It' shouldn't be. I'm using Vuetify and i assign variables like what you want and it works, because on runtime variables are already defined